# How do I remove trailing characters after Question mark(?) in a String?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I need to remove the trailing characters after 2 from the below String

```
String a = "12?34567";
```

My expected String output should be 12

I tried the below replaceAll method. But It did not work.

```
a.replaceAll("\\?+$", ""));
```

Please help

Comment: What happens if there are two or more question marks? Do you want the data removed from the first or the last? Your current expression is missing the part between the question mark and the end of the line.

Comment: use `indexOf` and `substring`.

Comment: I need the data to be removed from the first question mark occurrence.

Comment: And do you want to leave the question mark intact or remove it as well?

Comment: question mark should be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, use indexOf:

```
final int index = orig.indexOf('?');
return index == -1 ? orig : orig.subString(0, index);
```

If you want to leave the question mark as is, just add 1 to `index` in the substring operation above.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the digits in your regex, you are just checking for one or more instances of the questionmark. This should do what you are trying to achive.

```
String a = "12?34567";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\?\\d*$", ""));
```

If you just want to remove them after the first questionmark as stated in your comment you could simply do

```
String a = "12??1?1231";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\?.*", ""));
```

Comment: The conditions doesn't state that there are only digits after the `?`. But `\\?.*$` should do it.

Comment: @ClasG i just orianted myself after his example, but changing `\\d*` to `.*` shouldn´t be that hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String a = "12?34567";
    String[] split = a.split("\\?");
    System.out.println(split[0]);
```